# Does var ALWAYS override globals?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, closures, scope

Is it correct to assume that omitting `var` from a `local` variable will

*ALWAYS* override a `global` of the same name, if it's also missing `var`?

Also, is there any merit to using `var` with creative license.

**So there's a frame of reference,** here is what I discovered

from riddles I created for [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082985/variable-scope-and-var).

In [Riddle #3](http://jsfiddle.net/Vz7Sd),

- omitting the `var` from `a = 5` overrides its `global` counterpart
- `b` remains polarized between `local` and `global`
- the `alert()` at the bottom returns 5*5+4+15
- 4 is the `local` `b`. 15 is the `global` `b`, declared on line 25

In [Riddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/FJVYL),

- omitting the `var` from `b = 4` overrides its `global` counterpart
- `a` remains polarized between `local` and `global`
- the `alert()` at the bottom returns 5*3+4+4 -
- 5 is the `local` `a`. 3 is the `global` `a`, declared on line 11

In [Riddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/gNEmY),

- omitting the `var` from both `local` variables overrides ALL `global` counterparts
- There is no distinction between `local` and `global` variables.
- the `alert()` at the bottom returns 5*5+4+4
- Only variables declared inside the `function` are recognized

Comment: They're called fiddles, not riddles ;)

Comment: Are you asking or telling?

Comment: please incorporate relevant code snippets in your question, not just references to jsfiddles.

Comment: @ToddMotto Just presenting what I found and asking for confirmation.

Comment: From what I see, your findings are correct.

Comment: @jovan I can't tell if you're joking? I was referring to the problems inside the fiddles, not the fiddles themselves.

Comment: Thanks @jovan How is `b` of `c = line(a) + b` on line 30 of Riddles [#1](http://jsfiddle.net/gNEmY) & [#2](http://jsfiddle.net/FJVYL) 'grammatically' allowed to overlook `b = line(a) - b` to access `b = 4` inside of the definition of `line` even though `b = line(a) - b` is defined AFTER the definition of `line`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No. `local` Scope doesn't override the `global` scope until AFTER the function is called.

[For Example:](http://jsfiddle.net//RaA5J/)

```
a = 3;
b = 2;

function line(x) {
    a = 5;
    b = 4;

    return a*x + b;
}

// returns 19 by referencing "global a = 3"
alert(line(a));

b = line(a) - b;

// returns 25 by referencing "local a = 5"
alert(b);
```

Omitting `var` disregards `global` variables (of identical name) once the `function line(x)` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables, and formal function parameters, will *always* override globals (or other variables declared in higher scopes).  However those local variables don't actually exist other than for the duration of the function call.

To see this, replace any *global* variable `a` or `b` with its upper-case equivalent (leaving any local re-declarations or use thereof in lower-case) and you'll find that your code works identically.

Comment: Thanks, I figured as much. I was more interested in 'why' but I realized the answer as I was responding to @jovan. Thanks again.